# CMFCColorButton does not appear in MFC class wizard dropdown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I was trying to create a CMFColorButton derived class with class wizard. However, in Visual Studio 2013 the CMFCColorButton parent class does not appear in the  "Base Class" dropdown in the class wizard.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please attach the screenshot demonstrating this behavior

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin how do I attach screenshot in StackOverflow?

Comment: manatttta, just click the image button to upload image: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive from a custom base class use the regular Add Class wizard rather than the MFC Add Class wizard.

- [Generic C++ Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af00tk82.aspx) [(alt)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/af00tk82(v=vs.120).aspx)
  [image]
- [MFC Add Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ayf8605.aspx) [(alt)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3ayf8605(v=vs.120).aspx)
  [image]

Comment: But is CMFCColorButton  a custom base class?

Comment: For some reason `CMFCColorButton` is not listed in "MFC Add Class Wizzard". But you should still be able to drive from it. The source code should be here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxcolorbutton.cpp`